# Show the ion-datetime using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I am trying to show the `<ion-datetime>` using Javascript code.

The HTML code I have is:

```
  <ion-item *ngIf="showDatePicker">
    <ion-label>CHANGE DATE</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime (ionChange)="dateSelected()" displayFormat="D MMM YYYY" min="2017" max="2030-12-31" [(ngModel)]="diaryDate"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

With this code the date picker appears when you click on the `<ion-label>`, but I want it to appear when I execute a bit of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

for example, you could create ref, then whenever button click, you will invoke `open()` method.

```
<ion-item *ngIf="showDatePicker">
   <ion-label>CHANGE DATE</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime #pick (ionChange)="dateSelected()" displayFormat="D MMM YYYY" min="2017" max="2030-12-31" [(ngModel)]="diaryDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

**button** somewhere

```
<button (click)="pick.open()">open</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Tiep. How do I do pick.open in the Javascript/Typescript file?

Comment: use ViewChild to query pick element, then call in your js/ts file, note that, maybe you cannot invoke `open()` method, because as the `datetime.d.ts` file, `constructor(_form: Form, config: Config, elementRef: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer, _item: Item, _pickerCtrl: PickerController);
    _click(ev: UIEvent): void;
    _keyup(): void;
    /**
     * @private
     */
    open(): void;` it's seem open is private, you could try with _keyup() method.

Comment: here is full file https://gist.github.com/tieppt/195531a0a7acdf14a23136b6bb68a539

Comment: Thanks Tiep I will see if I can make progress